# Regex match strings in bash

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash

I was curious if you can make regex to match 2nd character of a string with 2 from the back? For 1st and last its pretty easy and straightforward but i was curious if it can be done for any str length?  I was playing with it in bash for the last hour and none of my solutions seams to work.

`^(.).*\1$` thats the regex I have for 1st and last char it probably needs too be a little edited for this but i have no idea how.

Can you help me with the other one?

```
examples:
abcsba - match as b(index 1) == b(index -2)
regex - match as e(index 1) == a(index -2)
abba - match 
unix - not matcha as indexOf(n) != indexOf(i)
linux - not match as indexOf(i) != indexOf(u)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just discard equal number of character from the beginning and from the end:

```
$ pat='^.(.).*\1.$'
$ [[ abcsba =~ $pat ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ unix =~ $pat ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
```

or, generally use `{n}` (eg. to match 3rd character with 3rd from the end):

```
pat='^.{2}(.).*\1.{2}$'
$ [[ abcdef =~ $pat ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
$ [[ abccef =~ $pat ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

In the second example we use single-character-ERE [duplication operator `{m,n}`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04_06) defined in POSIX for both basic and extended regular expressions (ERE variant is only relevant here though, since `=~` operator in `bash` uses ERE). The `{n}` form is a special case, equal to `{n,n}`, meaning repeat the preceding character (or group) exactly `n` times.

Comment: When i'm using it to grep words that have the same 2nd and -2 string the same in grep -E '^.(.).*\1.$' it doesn't match all of the words like for example "did" so its like your regex doesnt like mine. When i run mine i have "did" in there and when im using mine and your together it doesnt match mine words.

Comment: That's because with `^.(.).*\1.$` we said that we want second character repeated as second to last. So, `abba` will match as well as `adida`.

Comment: Yes it works fine but it doesnt match words from previous grep. How can I join them so it will match both first last and 2nd and 2nd back?

Comment: You can combine them with alternation operator `|`, for example: `^(.).*\1$|^.(.).*\2.$`. You need to use `\2` in second part to match the second captured group.

Comment: Thank You I didnt even know I can join two regexes in one like this but here is another question. It will match for example abcbe. How can I restrict that 1st and last has to be the same and 2nd front and back has to be the same as well?

Comment: That's simple, too. Try: `^(.)(.).*\2\1$`. But please don't expand your original question in comments -- better ask a new one (and close this one by upvoting/accepting an answer). This is quite unreadable and not of much benefit for the next user that comes along.

Comment: It works only when string has more than 3 chars because it checks for 2 same letters on 2 positions. How about when the string has only 3 characters and first and last is the same? like "aba" "did" "owo"?
EDIT:
Ok that's my last question and I will close this one. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Please see my previous comment (btw, you can combine with `|`, like in the previous case).

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you want to extract the characters . You can do it by awk command

echo "praveen" | awk '{print substr($1,1,2)}'
pr
01HW497089:tmp Controller$

Here i am extracting column1 value from character 1 to character 3